Which is the proper test to use here? "A/B testing"
Noob question on which is the proper test to use.
We have 2 algorithms, the old one and a new one. With test data the algorithms are used to generated an output and then there are (for now) 3 raters rating which output is better. The rating is from 1 to 5.
So I have pairs of data 3 ratings for algorithm A, and 3 ratings for algorithm B.
What is now a appropriate way to determine of one algorithm is better than the other? To I take the mean of the ratings? Sum them up?  And then which specific test for significance should I use?
UPDATE:
it's 20 test samples so 40 ratings in total

Does each rater rate both new and old algo results for each test sample? How many samples do you have?

yes each rater rates both algos. for now there are 20 test samples, so 40 ratings per rater.

Please add relevant information such as the test sample number to the question rather than only mention this in a comment.

Can you post the data?

@dimitriy no can't really share the data

A quick and dirty solution would be a prop odds regression model with the ordinal rating as a response, model choice as a predictor, and a rater-level random effect. However, I think you’ll have identifiably issues with such a small sample size. This is also assuming that the task being evaluated is consistent between all trials, otherwise that variance needs to be accounted for.

The 1 to 5 rating looks and smells like a Likert scale? Can you describe exactly what it is, what each level is, and what it measures. If we do not know what the raters are rating, it is very hard to help you find a way to analyze this data.

@jginestet It's just about having different levels for the raters, it's quiet subjective and in practice not really an ordinal scale, more qualitative rating.

With the data in a long format (20 inputs x 3 raters x 2 algos = 120 rows of ratings), I would fit an ordered probit (or logit) model with a constant and a dummy for the new algo (B). Then, I would calculate the marginal effect of that dummy for each star rating. These give you the change in probability of each star rating from the new algo relative to the old algo.
This corresponds to an idealized experiment where you've sampled 20 representative inputs from an infinite population of potential inputs and given the outputs from the two algos to the three fixed raters. In other words, you are attempting to learn how the distribution of star ratings varies from algo A to algo B for these three raters (rather than a hypothetical superpopulation of raters).
In this situation, I would cluster the standard errors by input to relax the independence assumption. For instance, some inputs may be more challenging than others. Since you don't have a lot of data, I would also bootstrap the standard errors rather than relying on the asymptotic clustered approximation.
Below is an example of that using Stata. First, let's look at the simulated raw data:

Since most lines slope up, there is an improvement from using algo B on average.
The following chart compares the asymptotic clustered and bootstrapped clustered CIs. There is little difference here since the simulated DGP was pretty simple, so the asymptotic approximation is OK. However, you may see more of a difference between the two.
Here, the new algorithm reduces the probability of one—and two-star ratings and increases the probability of four—and five-star ratings. The effect is not statistically significant in the middle of the rating scale on three stars. All these effects are on a [0,1] scale, so they are meaningful. There is asymmetry. For instance, you could reject the null that the effect on 1 and 2 stars is the same, but you cannot do that at the top with 4 and 5.

If you don't care about each star rating separately and are instead interested in the average rating, you could just use regression or a count data model with the same right-hand-side and clustered & boostrapped errors.
It's possible to do something fancier, like including rater and item fixed/random effects or multiway clustering (say item and rater), but I would be wary of doing something very complicated with only 120 observations.

Here's the Stata code and output for the ordered probit:
. // This do-file performs an ordered probit regression with clustered asymptotic and bootstrapped 
. // standard errors.
. // It generates synthetic data for 1-5 star ratings given by 3 raters of 2 algo outputs for 20 inputs.
. // The code then reshapes the data to long format (20 inputs x 3 raters x 2 algos =  120 rows of ratings).
. // It then estimates an ordered probit model, and computes the marginal effect of treatment on 
. // each of the five possible ratings. Here treatment lowers the probability of 1
. // and 2 star ratings and raises it for 4 and 5 star rating, with no effect on 3
. // star ratings.
. //
. // It then does this using bootstrapped clustered standard errors for the marginal effects.
. // Finally, it conducts a join hypothesis test on the 5 marginal effects.
. 
. clear

. set seed 201

. set obs 20
Number of observations (_N) was 0, now 20.

. 
. // Generate unique input IDs
. gen input = _n

. 
. // Generate ratings for each rater and treated period
. forvalues r = 1(1)3 {
  2.     forvalues t = 0(1)1 {
  3.         gen rating_r`r'_t`t' = round(uniform()*(`t'+3) + 0.5 + `t')
  4.         assert inlist(rating_r`r'_t`t',1,2,3,4,5)
  5.     }   
  6. } 

. 
. // Reshape the data to long format: one rating observation per input, rater, and algo
. reshape long rating_r1_t rating_r2_t rating_r3_t, i(input) j(t) 
(j = 0 1)

Data                               Wide   ->   Long
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
Number of observations               20   ->   40          
Number of variables                   7   ->   5           
j variable (2 values)                     ->   t
xij variables:
              rating_r1_t0 rating_r1_t1   ->   rating_r1_t
              rating_r2_t0 rating_r2_t1   ->   rating_r2_t
              rating_r3_t0 rating_r3_t1   ->   rating_r3_t
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------

. rename (*_t) (*)

. 
. // plot the raw data
. xtset input t

Panel variable: input (strongly balanced)
 Time variable: t, 0 to 1
         Delta: 1 unit

. labvarch rating_r*, map(@)

. labvarch rating_r*, subst("rating_r" "Rater ")

. xtline rating_r1 rating_r2 rating_r3, xlab(#2) subtitle(, nospan) name(raw, replace) ///
> xlab(0 "A" 1 "B") ylab(#5) ytitle("Star Rating") xtitle("Algo") ///
> byopts(note("") title("Star Ratings by Item, Algo, and Rater"))

. 
. reshape long rating_r, i(input t) j(r)
(j = 1 2 3)

Data                               Wide   ->   Long
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
Number of observations               40   ->   120         
Number of variables                   5   ->   4           
j variable (3 values)                     ->   r
xij variables:
          rating_r1 rating_r2 rating_r3   ->   rating_r
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------

. rename (*_r) (*)

. sort input r t

. order input r t

. rename r rater

. rename t treated

. head

    input   rater   treated   rating  
        1       1         0        3  
        1       1         1        5  
        1       2         0        3  
        1       2         1        4  
        1       3         0        1  
        1       3         1        2  
        2       1         0        3  
        2       1         1        3  
        2       2         0        1  
        2       2         1        2  

. 
. // Estimate the ordered probit model with clustered standard errors
. // NB: These are only valid as number of inputs approaches infinity
. oprobit rating i.treated, vce(cluster input)

Iteration 0:   log pseudolikelihood = -188.19412  
Iteration 1:   log pseudolikelihood =   -157.702  
Iteration 2:   log pseudolikelihood = -157.34682  
Iteration 3:   log pseudolikelihood = -157.34663  
Iteration 4:   log pseudolikelihood = -157.34663  

Ordered probit regression                               Number of obs =    120
                                                        Wald chi2(1)  =  52.36
                                                        Prob > chi2   = 0.0000
Log pseudolikelihood = -157.34663                       Pseudo R2     = 0.1639

                                 (Std. err. adjusted for 20 clusters in input)
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
             |               Robust
      rating | Coefficient  std. err.      z    P>|z|     [95% conf. interval]
-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
   1.treated |   1.715701    .237099     7.24   0.000     1.250995    2.180406
-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
       /cut1 |  -.2614435    .118481                      -.493662   -.0292251
       /cut2 |   .3754942   .1389599                      .1031378    .6478505
       /cut3 |    1.50172   .0931237                      1.319201    1.684239
       /cut4 |   2.262205   .1574878                      1.953535    2.570876
------------------------------------------------------------------------------

. // Compute marginal effects
. margins, dydx(t) post

Conditional marginal effects                               Number of obs = 120
Model VCE: Robust

dy/dx wrt: 1.treated

1._predict: Pr(rating==1), predict(pr outcome(1))
2._predict: Pr(rating==2), predict(pr outcome(2))
3._predict: Pr(rating==3), predict(pr outcome(3))
4._predict: Pr(rating==4), predict(pr outcome(4))
5._predict: Pr(rating==5), predict(pr outcome(5))

------------------------------------------------------------------------------
             |            Delta-method
             |      dy/dx   std. err.      z    P>|z|     [95% conf. interval]
-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
0.treated    |  (base outcome)
-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
1.treated    |
    _predict |
          1  |  -.3728626   .0481083    -7.75   0.000    -.4671532    -.278572
          2  |  -.1834018   .0316448    -5.80   0.000    -.2454246   -.1213791
          3  |     .03813   .0475525     0.80   0.423    -.0550712    .1313313
          4  |   .2376172   .0479851     4.95   0.000     .1435681    .3316662
          5  |   .2805172    .052223     5.37   0.000      .178162    .3828724
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Note: dy/dx for factor levels is the discrete change from the base level.

. // Plot the marginal effects
. marginsplot, saving("m_input_clust", replace) yline(0) title("Input-Clustered SEs", nospan) ylab(#10) ///
> xtitle("Star Rating") ytitle("Effect on the Probability of Each Star Rating") nodraw

Variables that uniquely identify margins: _outcome
file m_input_clust.gph saved

. 
. // Estimate the ordered probit model with clustered BOOTSTRAPPED standard errors
. oprobit rating i.treated, vce(bootstrap, cluster(input) idcluster(newid) reps(5000) seed(1) nodots)

Ordered probit regression                               Number of obs =    120
                                                        Replications  =  5,000
                                                        Wald chi2(1)  =  50.63
                                                        Prob > chi2   = 0.0000
Log likelihood = -157.34663                             Pseudo R2     = 0.1639

                                  (Replications based on 20 clusters in input)
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
             |   Observed   Bootstrap                         Normal-based
      rating | coefficient  std. err.      z    P>|z|     [95% conf. interval]
-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
   1.treated |   1.715701   .2411141     7.12   0.000     1.243126    2.188276
-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
       /cut1 |  -.2614435   .1172979                     -.4913431   -.0315439
       /cut2 |   .3754942    .140716                      .0996959    .6512924
       /cut3 |    1.50172   .0971544                        1.3113    1.692139
       /cut4 |   2.262205    .163351                      1.942043    2.582367
------------------------------------------------------------------------------

. // Compute marginal effects
. margins, dydx(t) post //coefl

Conditional marginal effects                               Number of obs = 120
Model VCE: Bootstrap

dy/dx wrt: 1.treated

1._predict: Pr(rating==1), predict(pr outcome(1))
2._predict: Pr(rating==2), predict(pr outcome(2))
3._predict: Pr(rating==3), predict(pr outcome(3))
4._predict: Pr(rating==4), predict(pr outcome(4))
5._predict: Pr(rating==5), predict(pr outcome(5))

------------------------------------------------------------------------------
             |            Delta-method
             |      dy/dx   std. err.      z    P>|z|     [95% conf. interval]
-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
0.treated    |  (base outcome)
-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
1.treated    |
    _predict |
          1  |  -.3728626   .0477944    -7.80   0.000    -.4665379   -.2791873
          2  |  -.1834018    .032586    -5.63   0.000    -.2472693   -.1195344
          3  |     .03813   .0467009     0.82   0.414     -.053402     .129662
          4  |   .2376172   .0484862     4.90   0.000      .142586    .3326483
          5  |   .2805172   .0511058     5.49   0.000     .1803516    .3806828
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Note: dy/dx for factor levels is the discrete change from the base level.

. marginsplot, saving("m_input_bs_clust", replace) yline(0) title("Input-Clustered Bootstrapped SEs", nospan) ylab(#10) xtitle("Star Rating") ytitle("") nodraw

Variables that uniquely identify margins: _outcome
file m_input_bs_clust.gph saved

. 
. // Compare the asymptotic clustered and bootstrapped clustered CIs (point estimates will be the same)
. graph combine "m_input_clust.gph" "m_input_bs_clust.gph", ycommon xcommon name(g2, replace) rows(1) 

. 
. // Perform hypothesis test that all marginal effects are jointly zero
. test _b[1.treated:1._predict]== _b[1.treated:2._predict]== _b[1.treated:3._predict]== _b[1.treated:4._predict]== _b[1.treated:5._predict]== 0

 ( 1)  [1.treated]1bn._predict - [1.treated]2._predict = 0
 ( 2)  [1.treated]1bn._predict - [1.treated]3._predict = 0
 ( 3)  [1.treated]1bn._predict - [1.treated]4._predict = 0
 ( 4)  [1.treated]1bn._predict - [1.treated]5._predict = 0
 ( 5)  [1.treated]1bn._predict = 0
       Constraint 5 dropped

           chi2(  4) =  108.90
         Prob > chi2 =    0.0000


thanks I will have to digest this a bit longer and how I would implement that in say python or R as thats what I would have available.

This is a pretty standard command. Nothing exotic and lots of examples here.
